# Create new Python DataFrame column based on conditions of multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new DataFrame column (Column C) based on the inputs of two other columns. The two criteria I have is if either "Column A is > 0" OR "Column B contains the string "Apple",* then Column C should have the value of "Yes" otherwise it should have the value of "No"

*Bonus points if answer is not case-sensitive (that is, it'll pick up the "apple" in "Pineapple" as well as in "Apple Juice"

Data might look like (and what Column C should result in)

```
Column_A Column_B           Column_C  
23       Orange Juice       Yes  
2        Banana Smoothie    Yes  
8        Pineapple Juice    Yes  
0        Pineapple Smoothie Yes  
0        Apple Juice        Yes  
0        Lemonade           No  
34       Coconut Water      Yes
```

I've tried several things, including:

```
df['Keep6']= np.where((df['Column_A'] >0) | (df['Column_B'].find('Apple')>0) , 'Yes','No')
```

But get the error message: `"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `case=False` to **not case-sensitive**:

```
df['Column_C']= np.where((df['Column_A']>0) | (df['Column_B'].str.contains('apple', case=False)) ,'Yes','No')
print(df)
```

---

```
   Column_A            Column_B Column_C
0        23        Orange_Juice      Yes
1         2     Banana_Smoothie      Yes
2         8     Pineapple_Juice      Yes
3         0  Pineapple_Smoothie      Yes
4         0         Apple_Juice      Yes
5         0            Lemonade       No
6        34       Coconut_Water      Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, using [pandas.Dataframe.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```
df['Column_C'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Yes' if (row['Column_A']>0) | (row['Column_B'].lower().find('apple')>=0) else 'No', axis=1)
```

and gives:

```
   Column_A            Column_B Column_C
0        23        Orange Juice      Yes
1         2     Banana Smoothie      Yes
2         8     Pineapple Juice      Yes
3         0  Pineapple Smoothie      Yes
4         0         Apple Juice      Yes
5         0            Lemonade       No
6        34       Coconut Water      Yes
```